# какие версии intellij idea и pycharm, а также java и python подходят для windows 7 64 bit(профессиональная)?

Tags: python, java, intellij-idea, pycharm

какие версии intellij idea и pycharm, а также java и python подходят для windows 7 64 bit(профессиональная)?

Comment: пишешь в гугле `intellij idea системные требования` и читаешь

Comment: Все самые новые должны работать. Если нужно что-то старое, то нужно либо гуглить, либо пробовать. У PyCharm/IDEA Community Edition такие же требования как и у Pro/Ultimate - можно поставить посмотреть.

Comment: Спрашивали же не какую ось установить для актуальной IntelliJ, а какая версия IDE взлетит в семерке.